# when using mutex, "printf" output twice(or more?I'm not sure)?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, mutex

I was learning threading synchronization. My test code is as follow:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int count = 0;
void* add(void * params)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        fprintf(stdout, "thread:%ld, count:%d\n",pthread_self(), count);
        count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    return 0;
}

void* print(void * params)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (count > 100)
        {
            printf("count greater than 100,count: %d\n", count);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            break;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, add, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, add, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, print, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    return 0;
}
```

I thought every output of "count" will increased by one successively. However, the truth was quite different.Just like:

> //program output begin: thread:139663694870272, count:0
>   thread:139663694870272, count:1 thread:139663694870272, count:2
>   thread:139663694870272, count:3 thread:139663694870272, count:4
>   thread:139663694870272, count:5 thread:139663686477568, count:6
>   thread:139663686477568, count:7 thread:139663686477568, count:8
>   thread:139663686477568, count:9 thread:139663686477568, count:10
>   thread:139663686477568, count:11 thread:139663686477568, count:12
>   thread:139663686477568, count:13 thread:139663686477568, count:14
>   thread:139663686477568, count:15 thread:139663686477568, count:16
>   thread:139663686477568, count:17 thread:139663686477568, count:18
>   thread:139663686477568, count:19 thread:139663686477568, count:20
>   thread:139663686477568, count:21 thread:139663686477568, count:22
>   (...............some lines were ignored)thread:139663686477568,
>   count:172 count greater than 100,count: 173 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:173 thread:139663686477568, count:174 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:175 thread:139663686477568, count:176 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:177 thread:139663686477568, count:178 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:179 thread:139663686477568, count:180 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:181 thread:139663686477568, count:182 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:183 thread:139663686477568, count:184 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:185 thread:139663686477568, count:186 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:187 thread:139663686477568, count:188 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:189 thread:139663686477568, count:190 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:191 thread:139663686477568, count:192 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:193 thread:139663686477568, count:194 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:195 thread:139663686477568, count:196 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:197 thread:139663686477568, count:198 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:199 thread:139663686477568, count:200 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:201 thread:139663686477568, count:202 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:203 thread:139663686477568, count:204 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:205
>   **thread:139663686477568, count:206 thread:139663686477568, count:206** thread:139663686477568, count:207 thread:139663686477568,
>   count:208 thread:139663686477568, count:209
>   **thread:139663686477568, count:210 thread:139663686477568, count:210** thread:139663686477568, count:211

I don't konw what "printf" do in this case? Why it output twice.

Comment: You destroy the mutex after 100 iterations. I'm rather amazed that nothing else completely breaks.

Comment: What command line did you use to compile this code? Did you specify whatever your platform requires for POSIX pthreads support? (Probably `-pthread`.)

Comment: @David Schwartz    I just use "gcc pthread_mutex.c -lpthread" and "a.out" is my output file.

Comment: @seven You should use `-pthread`, not `-lpthread`. But it probably won't make any difference on your platform.

Comment: Are you sure your output came from the same program you post? The comma after the count appears in your output but nothing in your code produces such a thing.

Comment: Look again David.  There's a comma here:  `"thread:%ld, count:%d\n"`.  Although the "missing" newline is weird too....

Comment: @Brian McFarland that's someline which are not important!  I igore them.

Answer (score 3):

Once the mutex is destroyed, all bets are off. You should not destroy the mutex until you are sure that no thread can use it.

Comment: I still don't know what "printf" do in this case why it output twice with the same "count"! Could we ignore this problem when notice the time sequence of mutex.(just destroy it until no thread use it)

Comment: Your code has a bug. You destroy the mutex and then continue to try to use it. You just need to fix the bug. It really is that simple.

Answer (score 3):

David has the correct answer... don't destroy the mutex until all threads have exited.  I just wanted to expand on that a little since you seem to be just learning pthreads.

Try changing `add` to something like this:

```
void* add(void * params)
{
    int quit =0;
    while(!quit)
    {
        if( 0 == pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) )
        {
           fprintf(stdout, "thread:%ld, count:%d\n",pthread_self(), count);
           count++;
           if( count > 100 ) quit = 1;
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        else
        {
           fprintf(stderr, "Failed to lock mutex.  Exiting.\n");
           quit=1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are 2 big changes:

- Check the return value of `pthread_mutex_lock`.  **Always**.  You can inspect the return value to see why it failed, but usually if locking fails, you do not want to access the resource protected by the lock.
- It's also good practice for the `add` thread to know how/when to shut itself down.  What I've shown here is just one way to do it.

Also, FYI, the `pthread_mutex_destroy()` in main is far from being guaranteed to succeed anyway.  You cannot destroy a mutex while it is locked or referenced (e.g. by condition variables).  So if `add` has the lock when trying to destroy it, `pthread_mutex_destroy()` *should* return an error.

Comment: **important edit:**  Originally had `count > 0` instead of `count > 100` as the condition for setting `quit=1`.  I've fixed that now.

Comment: "*You can inspect `errno` to see ...*" No, recent PThread implementations do not set `errno`, but the error code is returned by the functions.

Comment: You're right alk.  thanks for the correction.  original post edited to reflect that.

Comment: Why not in your `add`: `int lim = 0;` at the beginning and then `lim++, count++;` before `if( lim > 50 ) quit = 1;`? Seems like that would allow `51` threads from each `add`.

Comment: I modify my program: add sleep(1) in the end of "main" to make sure the thread was exit before mutex destroy! And there is  no twice output any more.

Comment: @seven, you shouldn't ever need to `sleep` to guarantee a thread you wrote has exited.  That's what `join` (and/or status variables) is for.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - That works too, but at that point, I would just use a `for` loop.  Which way is "best" depends on what you're doing.  If this were a "real world" problem and not a toy program, we could probably arrive at a better answer.